# How do you transform Flash in Safari?

Tags: css, css-transforms

The transform functions work fine in Chrome. They work fine in safari unless you are trying to transform a java applet or flash and the like. Is there a way to get the transform to work?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9W7A/5/)

```
"-webkit-transform": "scaleX(.5) scaleY(.5) rotateY(25deg)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer http://viget.com/inspire/webkit-transform-kill-the-flash. You have to give it an initial rotate.

```
// relevantformattedcode;
```

Adjusted [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9W7A/6/)